# Admob real ads not showing on flutter app but java app works

Tags: android, flutter, admob

First I created android app using java and admob real ads showing perfectly. Then I create another android app using flutter, I run with test ads first and that works fine. But then I use the same unit id and app id but real ads not showing on flutter app.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'ad_state.dart';
import 'home.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);

  runApp(
    Provider.value(
      value: adState,
      builder: (context, child) => MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'ad_state.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  BannerAd banner;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);
    adState.initialization.then((status) {
      setState(() {
        banner = BannerAd(
          size: AdSize.banner,
          adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
          listener: adState.bannerAdListener,
          request: AdRequest(),
        )..load();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Admob"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Text("Hello World"),
            if (banner == null)
              SizedBox(height: 50)
            else
              Container(
                height: 50,
                child: AdWidget(
                  ad: banner,
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("Hello World");
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ad_state.dart:

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class AdState {
  Future<InitializationStatus> initialization;

  AdState(this.initialization);

  String get bannerAdUnitId => '<Banner_Unit_ID>';

  BannerAdListener get bannerAdListener => _adListener;

  BannerAdListener _adListener = BannerAdListener(
    // Called when an ad is successfully received.
    onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) => print('Ad loaded.'),
    // Called when an ad request failed.
    onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
      // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
      ad.dispose();
      print('Ad failed to load: $error');
    },
    // Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen.
    onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('Ad opened.'),
    // Called when an ad removes an overlay that covers the screen.
    onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('Ad closed.'),
    // Called when an impression occurs on the ad.
    onAdImpression: (Ad ad) => print('Ad impression.'),
  );
}
```

Following Error shows:
**Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: []))**

Comment: Show some code. Where are you running the app, physical device, emulator?

Comment: I run on Physical device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uploaded app on play store. After uploading on play store ads are showing successfully.

Answer (score 1):

When building app in flutter unfortunately you can not check the real ads during development stages, you can use testAd id's and check if the ads run properly or not. only after uploading on playstore would the real ads run. (i ran into similar situation hope it helps.)